# Map Viewer in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, google-maps, html

For my new pet project, I'd like to develop a Map Viewer application similar to that of Google Maps

and

it should use all the new features of HTML5 and CSS3 where it can

hence

only new browser with HTML5 and CSS3 support can display it properly.

Any idea what kind of javascript framework combinations I should start using ?

Comment: Personally, I'd start with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [geo location JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/) to target any geo capable browser. Great library I personally use.